# Double Carot in Assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm working with some assembly at the moment and I was wondering what the following code meant, specifically the double carot (<<)

```
.EQU LED0 , 0
.EQU LED1 , 1
.EQU LED2 , 2
.EQU LED3 , 3

ldi R16, (1<<LED0 | 1<<LED1 | 1<<LED2 | 1<<LED3)
```

Is this shifting values somehow? I'm a little confused.
Note...this is for 8-bit Atmel Instruction Sets.

Comment: that is C syntax infecting assembly language, yes.  Not sure about that case but more and more I see folks adding C to their assembly and feeding it through a C pre-processor (because it isnt really assembly if the assembler pukes on it) first.

Comment: I'm not at all experienced in this field (about 2 weeks worth actually) so I'm not one to know. :) All I know is that my instructor used it in an example in class.

Comment: Note that this is an expression which will reduce to a constant early in the assembly; no shift operation is actually occurring at runtime.

Comment: I am just venting is all.  yes that appears to be C like syntax, which your tools may or may not be quite happy with.  It basically is loading r16 with 0xF  1<<3 is bit 0x8, 1<<2 is bit 0x4, 1<<1 is bit 0x2 and 1<<0 is bit 0x1.  or those all together using the C like or operator (|) and you get 0xF.  And this is all at compile time not runtime.  this makes it easier to maintain if for example you want to change bits/gpio, etc you can just change the equ for one of them and not have to run through all of your code changing magic hardcoded values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's creating 4 constants (`LED0` through `LED3`) which have numeric values corresponding to `0` through `3`.

Those values are then being used (likely by the C-preprocessor) to build another constant at compile time: `1<<0 | 1<<1 | 1<<2 | 1<<3`

The resulting value is `1111` in binary, or `15` in decimal.

You could just replace the whole parenthetical expression with the constant decimal expression `15`.